# Generate Debug & Release simultaneously

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is my situation. I've multiple projects / solutions that are linked.

- Solution A.sln

  - AA.csproj
  - AB.csproj
- Solution B.sln

  - BA.csproj references **bin\$(Configuration)\AA.exe**
  - BB.csproj references **bin\$(Configuration)\AB.exe**

(I modified the .csproj manually in order to reference the current configuration and not always Debug or Release).

I do that because I won't include all referenced projects I need directly in my solution to not polluate it.

So, in order to be always up-to-date, I want to generate both, Debug & Release configuration when building referenced projects. It's possible?

Comment: Can't you add a post build step to build whatever you need?

Comment: I can add post build step, but what should I specify as post build? It's a good practice to do this like that?

Comment: I tried to add `msbuild` as post-build event, but doing so, it will be launched recursively, so isn't a good idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Batch Build**.

Open *Build->Batch Build...* in solution *A*, select all projects you need in all configurations (Debug, Release,...) you need and click *Build* button.

VS will remember your selection for next batch build. So you just need to enter *Alt+B, Alt+T, Enter* for next build.

Comment: Ok, so I've just to remember to use batch build each time and not build. Will try so, thanks :)